# SVG in DIV not showing when added to DOM with coordinates of a certain HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a browser extension, I am testing it on Chrome and Edge for now.
It puts a svg drawing upon some words that are in the web page adjusting its size according to the font.

Simple divs with the svg inside are added to the DOM.
I put zIndex= auto or inherit but I found a strange behaviour on a certain web page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript

If the extension puts a drawing on the words matching "tabs" the first occurrence in the title you can see on top of the page is not seen at all.
I checked with the developer tools and the div is present like others, just it does not appear.

```
function createDiv(x,y,size) {
       var scrollX=window.scrollX;
            var scrollY=window.scrollY;
        var div=null;div=document.createElement('div');


            div.className=CLASS_NAME;
            div.style.position = 'absolute';
            var color=COLOR;

            div.style.opacity='0.6';

            div.style.zIndex='auto';

            div.style.top=(scrollY+(y)-size/4)+'px';
             div.style.height=(size)+'px';
             div.style.left=(scrollX+(x))+'px';
             if (scrollX+(x)+size>window.innerWidth) div.style.left=window.innerWidth-size;
             div.style.width=(size)+'px';

             div.innerHTML='<svg ...>';
             div.style.visibility='visible';
        return div;
        };
....
div=createDiv(param1,param2,param3);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

(52.71875 118 110 for the parameters should be matching the first occurrence)

Is it a zIndex issue? Or another kind of HTML problem?

Comment: Please show an actual executable example of this, so that we can see what it actually does to the page in question. (F.e. rewrite it so that it can be applied via the browser console, when visiting that page.)

Comment: @misorude You can try with these 3 parameters: 52.71875,118,110. I think you can set the innerHTML field as you want. Perform your test on the above mentioned web page.

Comment: Sorry, not able to reproduce the issue you are describing doing that.

Comment: @misorude Do you mean you see the div correctly displayed?

Comment: `z-index: auto` is not going to work, the `.document-head` element that contains that headline has `z-index: 88`, so you need to go at least that high with the z-index on your element as well, if you want to see it on top.

Comment: @misorude Shouldn't "inherit" be the same zIndex of the document? So I should see the div because that element with zIndex=88 shouldn't be able to hide the document.

Comment: _“Shouldn't "inherit" be the same zIndex of the document?”_ - a _document_ itself doesn’t have a z-index, only _elements_ inside it do. And it is not “hiding the document”, it is hiding a different element located _in_ that document, because that other element has a lower z-index.